# Sort facebook friends by gender

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to find friends who are only male or female in my friend list or in my friend's friend list?

Because i see only **All Friends**,**Mutual Friends**,**Recently Added**,**People You May Know**,**Followers** only when i visit friends list on my profile or my friends profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all of your friends who are male or female, type one of the following into the main search box at the top of the Facebook page and then press Enter:

> My friends who are male
>
> My friends who are female

To find all of the people in your friend's friend list who are male or female, type one of the following into the main search box at the top of the Facebook page and press Enter (you'll want to replace [name of friend] with your friend's name):

> Friends of [name of friend] who are male
>
> Friends of [name of friend] who are female

Note that Facebook will only find those people who have filled in the gender in their profile.  Facebook will not find anyone who hasn't filled in the gender in their profile.

Comment: how about the people who are not my friends??

Comment: @BarathVutukuri You can type in `People who are not my friends and who are male`

Comment: I meant a person who is not my friend but his friends who are male or female.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri Can you please post this as another question?  This is outside the scope of your original question.  Thanks.

Comment: Does not works!